# How to dynamically assign asp.net control ID's

Tags: asp.net

I want to do something like the following in an asp.net web form but get a Invalid Token error message:

```
<ul>
    <%foreach (var item in Items) {%>
    <li>
      <asp:TextBox ID="<%= item.Id  %>" runat="server" />
    </li>
    <%} %>
</ul>
```

What alternative methods are there to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Server side controls (i.e. those with `runat="server"`) have to have IDs set at compile time (because the ID is used to name the member field representing the control).

Either:

- Use some form of repeater control (i.e. create a collection of controls) and data binding to populate.
- create HTML (i.e. not server side controls) directly.

In ASP.NET the former is usual, with ASP.NET MVC the latter (via HTML Helpers) is usual.

Comment: By creating HTML directly can i get the control on a postback?  Or do i need to specify the ID attribute?

Comment: @Akk: you can access the value from `Request.Form` of any input element, but there will be no ASP.NET control.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to following approach:-

```
    foreach (Item item in items) 
    {
       TextBox txtBox=new TextBox();
       txtBox.ID=item.ID;
       placeHolder.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
```

Also make sure you dont have any invalid character like ("-"), it can create problem for you sometimes.